# How do I email out ApostropheCMS contact form submissions?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I created a contact-form module per this documentation: https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/forms.html

Submissions work and submitted forms are showing under "Contact Forms" admin menu item.

I also want generate an email to a recipient email address for each submission. **apostrophe-pieces-submit-widgets** states that I can `override the beforeInsert method to send email, if desired.`

However, I'm not sure where I should override this method.

Should I add a `beforeInsert` method inside **/lib/modules/contact-form/index.js** `self.submit` method?

Or, should I create a project-level copy of **apostrophe-pieces-submit-widgets**, and override the `beforeInsert` method there (I feel like this is probably *too* global and therefore not ideal)?

Lastly, should I involve **apostrophe-email**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer here assumes you are in fact using `apostrophe-pieces-submit-widgets`. So you haven't had to write very much code so far. You have a pieces module already, let's call it `products`, and you have made a submit widgets module, `products-submit-widgets`, which extends `apostrophe-pieces-submit-widgets`. OK, great. Let's talk about how to take it the rest of the way to sending email.

The `beforeInsert` method intentionally starts out doing nothing at all, as it is your opportunity to do "something extra" in your project level code.

To override that method, create `lib/modules/products-submit-widgets/index.js` if you have not already done so. You probably already have that file with `addFields` and `extend` etc. per the documentation for `apostrophe-pieces-submit-widgets`.

Now your code can look like this:

```
module.exports = {

  // ALL OF YOUR EXISTING CONFIGURATION OF THE products-submit-widgets
  // MODULE STILL GOES HERE, then...

  construct: function(self, options) {
    self.beforeInsert = function(req, piece, callback) {
      return self.email(req, 'emailSubmission', {
        piece: piece
      }, {
        // can also specify from and other
        // valid properties for nodemailer messages here
        to: 'admin@example.com',
        subject: 'A new submission was received'
      }, callback);
    };
  }
}
```

Now, in `lib/modules/my-pieces-module-name-submit-widgets/views` at **project level**, create an `emailSubmission.html` file and populate it like this:

```
<h4>A new submission was received</h4>

A new submission was received from {{ piece.someFieldOrOther }}.

It contains this information:

{{ piece.someOtherField }}
{{ piece.yetAnotherField }}
{{ piece.etc }}
```

So far so good! But, in order for the `self.email` method to work, you do need to configure the `apostrophe-email` module. A bare-bones configuration might look like this, if you have an email delivery agent on your Linux server already:

```
// in app.js
modules: {
  'apostrophe-email': {
    // Default "from" address. Note your email can be dropped as spam
    // if this address is invalid or your server has no right to send
    // email for it
    from: '"Jane Doe" <jane@doe.com>',
    // See the nodemailer documentation, many
    // different transports are available, this one
    // matches how PHP does it on Linux servers
    nodemailer: {
      sendmail: true,
      newline: 'unix',
      path: '/usr/sbin/sendmail'
    }
  }
}
```

But, for more complete information on that please see [sending email from your Apostrophe project](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/howtos/email.html). If you use a naive configuration your emails may be dropped as spam. If you don't plan to use a service like Amazon Simple Email Service or Postmark, and your volume is low, you can configure nodemailer to send messages through a valid gmail account without too much work.

Hope this is helpful! It would be a great PR to add this as an optional built-in feature of the apostrophe-pieces-submit-widgets module.

Comment: Actually didn't use apostrophe-submit-widgets... instead created a module per this: https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/forms.html#going-deeper-with-apostrophe-creating-a-code-contact-form-code-module

Does that change a lot? Would I be modifying the module index.js, or widget index.js?

Comment: That article starts by recommending pieces-submit-widgets. Then teaches how to reinvent it from scratch, if you really want to.

Comment: I would recommend using pieces-submit-widgets, otherwise you will need to compare its code to yours (which we don't see here) to understand how to adapt my answer for it.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!